# Possible to monkeypatch numpy array slice behavior?

Tags: python, arrays, monkeypatching

I know monkeypatching is frowned upon (for good reason), but this would only be in a script that nobody else would ever have to deal with. And I'd like to understand Python a bit better :)

Python doesn't throw an error if the bounds of a slice exceed the length of the thing being sliced. For example:

```
>>> 'abc'[10:20]
''
```

Which is all fine and good, but what if you'd like to have an error thrown? Specifically, when using Numpy arrays. I would like to have something like

```
# This will not work! 
import numpy as np

old_getitem = np.array.__getitem__

def new_getitem(self, val):
    if isinstance(val, slice):
        if val.stop >= len(self):
            raise IndexError
    return old_getitem(self, val)

np.array__getitem__ = new_getitem
```

but this can't work since np.array doesn't have a `__getitem__` attribute

```
>>> np.array.__getitem__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

what I find odd is that the following works:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a.__getitem__(slice(0,2))
array([1, 2])
```

My first guess would have been that Numpy is using the attribute of a parent class, but (as far as I know) it doesn't have one as a 'builtin_function_or_method'

So I have two questions. Is it possible to do my silly monkeypatch? And why does calling `__getitem__` on a Numpy array work when it doesn't have a `__getitem__` attribute?

Comment: `numpy.array` is a constructor function, not a type. The type is `numpy.ndarray` (but you can't monkey-patch methods on that either).

Comment: ah, that explains why ```__getitem__``` worked without being listed. Thank you :)

Comment: doing a bit more searching, I found a comment from Guido van Rossum answering a slightly different question [link](https://grokbase.com/t/python/python-dev/096ex98mgb/exception-for-setting-attributes-of-built-in-type) that adds a few more words to "you can't change attributes for built-ins". I guess that's the general take-away?